# spring security architecture filter chain and request matcher

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have been reading spring security docs which is from [here](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture) . 
There is an example:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10)
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/foo/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/foo/bar").hasRole("BAR")
        .antMatchers("/foo/spam").hasRole("SPAM")
        .anyRequest().isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

And it says

> One of the easiest mistakes to make with configuring Spring Security is to forget that these matchers apply to different processes, one is a **request matcher** for the whole **filter chain**, and the other is only to choose the access rule to apply.

I want to learn what it is this **forget** ? I couldn't get the relation and **filter chain** and **request matcher**

Answer (score 2):

It is a very convoluted way to say:

1. .anyRequest().isAuthenticated(); makes sure that to access any url in your application, a user needs to be authenticated.
2. In addition, the two ant matchers are simply checking the needed roles (=access rules), in addition to the user being authenticated.

The paragraph is badly written, imho.